# Making a submit button as an extension of a form in CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

This is what my form/submit button currently looks like:

[image: form submit screenshot]

I would like, of course, for the "Go" button to be better integrated into the rest of the form so that it appears as a seamless extension. This would mean that the right side would have a border-radius, while the left side would remain straight. In addition, the top and bottom of the button would have to line up perfectly with the top and bottom of the form.

Any help with this? I've been fiddling around, and this is what I've come up with so far in terms of code:

```
input {
    display: inline;
}

input.button {
    margin-left: -9px; 
    border: none;
    background-color:#FA8801;
    border-radius-right: 2px !important;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:7px 5px;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    font-family: inherit;
}

/*This is the styling for the form, not the button from here and on... */
input[type=email] {
    padding: 5px !important; 
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 100 !important;
} 
input[type=email]:focus { 
    border: 2px solid #FA8801; 
    outline: none; 
}
input[type=email]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color:transparent; 
}
```

And the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wfhLnsez/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` to target individual corners.

I would suggest putting a line-height on your input box which gives you the height you'll need for your "Go" submit button. Then you'll need to pad the left and right of these elements only seeing as you already have the height.

```
input.button {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; /* to match border-radius on input box */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px; /* to match height of input box */
    padding: 0 5px;
}

input[type=email] {
    line-height: 30px; /* height of input box */
    padding: 0 5px; /* nothing on top and bottom, 5px on left and right */
}
```

I've noticed you have `!important` on conflicting properties on your `input[type=email]`.

`-webkit-border-radius: 2px !important;
 border-radius: 5px !important;`

For starters, do your utmost to avoid using `!important` as well-written CSS shouldn't need them. You have 2 different values for the same property 2px and 5px. They should both be the same. Also, while you're at it, you should add the third prefix for these types of styles, so it should be:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you want:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfhLnsez/5/)

Some highlights:

- the border radius, you need to use all the browser's CSS for this:

  ```
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  ```
- I also change the padding to get the height of the button closer to made that of the input:

  ```
  padding-left:4px;
  padding-right:4px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  ```
- Finally, I moved the button over one pixel to cover the rest of the input's border radius:

  ```
  margin-left: -10px;
  ```

Hopefully this helps!